# Not able to break out of while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I have the following code:

```
with open('data.csv') as csvfile:
    data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    row_count = sum(1 for row in data)
    counter = 0
    while counter < row_count:
        for i in range(20):
            print('hello')
        counter = counter +1
        print('sleeping')
        time.sleep(10)
```

The `data.csv` file have over 100 lines. But I want my counter to print only 20 lines of hello and then sleep for 10 seconds and restart the operation again until it matches the number in `row_count`.

The output is fine in that it prints hello 20 times and prints sleep with a delay but this loop does not end when it reaches `row_count` which is 100. This keeps on running. What can I do for this loop to end after it reaches 100?

Comment: it doesn't end after 100 iterations?

Comment: no i let the program run in counted in excel it had over 2000 rows

Comment: use for-loop then, 
for i in range(0, row_count)

Comment: `row_count` equals the number of lines in the file. Where are you getting the number 100 if the file has 2000 lines?

Comment: If you want to stop at 100, not 2000-whatever, then set `row_count = 100`.

Comment: file data.csv has only 100 rows in it. So i could get hellp and the program should end . But When i run the code and copy paste the output in excel it had 2000 so it is running to infinity

Comment: @chepner row_count should come from the number of lines in file, i cannot manually set the row count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your identation is incorrect. If you ident the line where you increment the counter it will do what you want. Currently you are doing 100 (or whatever row_number equals) lots of 20.

EDIT: I wrote this thinking that you wanted to print "Hello" `row_number` times, but reading your post back it seems that you actually want to print "Hello" `row_number * 20` times, in which case surely 2000 is the correct answer?

Comment: I want to print hello 20 times. and then sleep after that. You have solved it thanks!